# Best way to transfer files from one server to another server in chef

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

I am trying to automate Oracle dataguard implementation. We need to transfer files from primary node to secondary node.

Please help me if any one has done such implementation and any best way for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what the contents of the file are, exactly.

If you have a static file then you can place your file in your cookbook under

```
<cookbookname>\files\default
```

and move them onto the node in the recipe by using the cookbook_file resource,

```
cookbook_file 'filename.ext' do
  path 'path\to\where\the\file\will\be
  action :create_if_missing
end
```

The action :create_if_missing will only put the file there if the path doesn't already exist.

More docs on cookbook_file: https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html

If your file needs to be dynamic, such that it contains different content based on the server you're running it on, you'll need a template resource and accompanying template file.

Template files go in

```
<cookbookname>\templates\default
```

They need to be named

```
<filename>.<fileextension>.erb
```

and they will be formatted exactly as your file needs to be formatted with the exception of the variable values you put in them. Variables are denoted by either

```
<% ruby code to evaluate here %>
```

or

```
<%= value to interpolate here %>
```

in other words you can use do

```
<% if condition %>
This will only show up in your created file if the condition is true
<% end %>
```

or you can do

```
mysitename = <%= @sitename %>
```

which will cause your recipe to replace the <%=%> tag with the value of @sitename.

Templates are used by doing the following in your recipe

```
template 'path/file/will/be/placed/at' do
  variables(
    variable_name_1: variable_value,
    variable_name_2: variable_value,
    ...
    variable_name_n: variable_value
  )
end
```

The path should end in the same file name as the template you wish to use minus the .erb extension. Note that the variable_names do not start with @, but when you use them in the template file you'll need to prepend them with @.

More info on templates at https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am looking for code to transfer files in one node to another node. Something like scp command.

Comment: Ah.. I see. That's a stateful operation, which I would not recommend using Chef for but you can execute arbitrary code with an exec resource. If the file needs to be present during a converge you might need to do something hacky, like skipping code that relies on that file the first converge. I'm not sure how the timing will work out.

Comment: correction, its an execute resource as in

    execute 'command line code to execute'